# NGINX -Rewrite url keeping part of url

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

Please help me to create nginx redirect like below:

```
https://mypage.com?via=181696076 -> https://newpage.com/checkout/?cc=GS950N&short_id=gi&via=181696076
```

The parameter(181696076) will change, will be only a number and will not have a fixed length
Can I do this using location?

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://newpage.com/checkout/?cc=GS950N&short_id=gi&$1;
```

I tried few combination, but it does not work for me - like the rewriting on server level

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found such solution for this problem:

```
  location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
return 301 https://newpage.com/checkout/?cc=GK960N&short_id=gi&via=$1;
```

}